# Как подключиться к postgre (docker) вне контейнера?

Tags: php, postgresql, docker

PHP:

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=messenger user=admin password=root")
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx-front:
    image: nginx:1.17.8
    volumes:
    - ./code-front:/code
    - ./docker/nginx-front.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-front.conf
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.240.2
  nginx-back:
    image: nginx:1.17.8
    volumes:
    - ./public:/code-back
    - ./code-back:/code
    - ./docker/nginx-back.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-back.conf
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.240.3
  php-back:
    image: php:8-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./code-back:/code
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.240.4
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13.3
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "messenger"
      POSTGRES_USER: "admin"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "root"
    volumes:
      - ../2. Init Database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./messenger:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  
networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.240.0/24
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8-fpm

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql
```

При исполнении этих фалов выходит ошибка:

```
Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? in /code/index.php on line 2
```

Comment: Указывайте ipv4_address и для postgres,  по нему и соединяйтесь. Localhost адрес = 127.0.0.1 для PHP контейнера, что значит что он будет стучаться по сам к себе.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, всё работает!